# Gostaria de uma breve explicação de como preencher uma combobox em padrão MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Gostaria de uma breve explicação de como preencher uma combobox em padrão MVVM. As tres partes, Model, View e ViewModel preenchido com a tabela do Banco De Dados.

Model:

```
class Racas : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _cd_Raca;
    private string _nm_Raca;

    public int Cd_Raca
    {
        get { return _cd_Raca ; }
        set
        {
            _cd_Raca = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChanged("Cd_Raca");
        }
    }
    public string Nm_Raca
    {
        get { return _nm_Raca; }
        set
        {
            _nm_Raca = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChanged("Nm_Raca");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyOfPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

View (XAML - WPF):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="dsCmbRaca" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
 Margin="438,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Height="19"/>
```

Não sei como implementar o ViewModel para que ele preencha a ComboBox com os dados da tabela Access que são Cd_Raca e Nm_Raca

Comment: Tente implementar ou se já tiver algum código poste para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Coloque o código

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Eu uso a ViewModel para montar a lista de itens que eu quero para popular o combobox.

Por exemplo:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListaItens}" SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSelecionado}" />
```

As variáveis 'ListaItens' e 'ItemSelecionado' são propriedades da ViewModel de um tipo qualquer. O 'ItemSelecionado' pode também ser algum atributo de um objeto.

Então no ViewModel eu carrego essa lista com os itens do banco de dados, no meu caso eu uso o Nhibernate como ORM para ajudar.

Abraços!