# ComboBox em WPF - Como preencher usando MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Estou com dúvidas em como popular um ComboBox em WPF usando o padrão MVVM. Aqui no Stackoverflow existe uma perguntar similar a minha, porém, não foi respondida (**[Gostaria de uma breve explicação de como preencher uma combobox em padrão MVVM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64627/gostaria-de-uma-breve-explica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-como-preencher-uma-combobox-em-padr%C3%A3o-mvvm)**).

Pesquisei e vi que as pessoas misturavam um pouco a camada de Persistencia com a View (code-behind). Acredito que não estejam obedecendo o MVVM.

**Queria saber qual a melhor forma de listar itens em uma `ComboBox` que estejam no banco de dados usando o padrão MVVM.**

ps.: Caso eu esteja errado sobre o padrão MVVM, peço que expliquem o por que.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!

Eu uso a ViewModel para montar a lista de itens que eu quero para popular o combobox.

Por exemplo:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListaItens}" SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSelecionado}" />
```

As variáveis '*ListaItens*' e '*ItemSelecionado*' são propriedades da ViewModel de um tipo qualquer. O '*ItemSelecionado*' pode também ser algum atributo de um objeto.

Abraços!

Comment: Muito legal! Acabei descobrindo [neste site](http://www.dotnetforall.com/combobox-binding-in-wpf-using-mvvm/). Muito obrigado!

Comment: Eu não sei o quão experiente você é com WPF. Mas esse site me ajudou bastante no começo: [link](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Home.html). É bem tranquilo de entender, e tem bastantes explicações de componentes. Abraços e sucesso!!

Comment: Eu também uso este site, mas não achei o que queria nele.